# Where to find CDH and all its software versions?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I want to know what is the CDH version currently being used most and Its all software version in detail. I.e.: If CDH 5.6 then what is the MapReduce, Hive, Impala, Sqoop etc version in this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most used? You're not going to be able to find that information unless Cloudera collected it and published the CDH versions their clients use.

Click the respective CDH version here for version information

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_vd_cdh_package_tarball.html

For example, Hadoop is at `2.6.0` , Sqoop is at `1.4.6` for CDH 5.6